# how do I avoid the 'index out of range' error here?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

How do I avoid the error I'm getting in this function? I don’t really understand why I'm getting this error, I just can't think of a solution. I would greatly appreciate any tips! thank you.

```
def myfunction(p):
    result = []
    count = 1
    if not p:
        return result
    else:
        if p[0] == p[1]:
            count + 1
            return myfunction(p[1:])
        else:
            result += (p[0],count)
            count = 1
            return myfunction(p[1:])
```

the function should return something like this:

```
myfunction("qqwweerrttyy")
[("q",2),("w",2),("e",2),("r",2),("t",2),("y",2)]
```

The error is:

```
  File "test.py", line 36, in myfunction
    return myfunction(p[1:])
  File "test.py", line 32, in myfunction
    return myfunction(p[1:])
  File "test.py", line 30, in myfunction
    if p[0] == p[1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: hahah sorry just fixed it there

Comment: then why this line: p = "qqwweerrttyy" ? if you receive p as arg

Comment: did you want to set a default value for p? if yes, do def `myfunction(p="qqwweerrttyy"):`

Comment: im sorry i just realised i made a load of mistakes but i think iv fixed them all now sorry, lol

Comment: @user1234567 please accept the most helpful answer (by clicking the checkmark next to the answer); it really sucks when we spend time debugging your code only to then be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you index `p[1]` even when `p` might contain a single element; you have to make sure that `p[1]` exists. You probably also want to say `count += 1`, not `count+1`, which doesn't seem to do any work in the code you gave. (I'm assuming `count` and `result` are global variables; otherwise the code makes no sense.)

Here's a working code:

```
count = 1
result = []
def myfunction(p):
    global count
    global result
    if not p:
        return result
    else:
        if len(p) >= 2 and p[0] == p[1]: # Make sure p[1] exists
            count += 1
            return myfunction(p[1:])
        else:
            result += (p[0],count)
            count = 1
            return myfunction(p[1:])
```

For example, when given the string `"lllalala"` the output is as expected:

```
>>> myfunction("lllalala")
['l', 3, 'a', 1, 'l', 1, 'a', 1, 'l', 1, 'a', 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your function, the one you asked about, is this:  you check if `p` is empty, but then you access two elements `p[0]` and `p[1]`.  You need to check that `p` has at least two elements before you can access `p[1]`.

```
if len(p) < 2:
    return result
else:
    if p[0] == p[1]:
        ...
```

After you fix this you'll find the next bug.

Comment: It seems you introduced a bug: the last letter won't be recorded in this case.

Comment: @blazs Only sort-of. Regardless of that the function always returns an empty list, since none of the intermediate results are part of the return value (ever).  : )  You changed the semantics by using global variables instead of pure recursion, which hides this bug.